# Check for errors (any) on guest entry form (Craft 3)

Tags: error, guest-entries, frontend-form

I have a guest entry form that's working fine. I'm using Craft-supplied code:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
  {% if errors %}
    {% for error in errors %}
      {{ error }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

And it works fine - field by field:

```
{% if entry is defined %}
  <p class="help alert">{{ errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

But I can't figure out how to check if there are any errors (and error in any field) so I can display a notification at the top of the page: "There were some problems with your submission".

```
{% if errorList(entry.getErrors())|length }}
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
{% if entry.hasErrors() %}
    Render a message here
{% endif %}
```